# Stroustrup Chapter4 Exercise 11

Tags: c++

I am working through Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ and I am on chapter 4, exercise 11. The question wants you to write a program that detects all primes between 1 ans 100. This is what I have so far

```
//This program finds the prime numbers between 1 and 100 
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int>primes;
bool ptest(int y)
{
    int p=0, x=0;
    for (x==0; x<primes.size(); ++p)
    {
        if (y%primes[x]==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
            return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i=3;
    primes.push_back(2);
    vector<int>comp;
    for (i==3; i<=100; ++i)
    {
        if (ptest(i)==true)
        {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }

    }

    for (int x:primes)
    {
        cout << x << " ";
    }

}
```

For some reason, the program prints 2, followed by all of the odds from 3-100. I am not sure what I am missing here.

EDIT: Question has been answered. The`p` was from a previous try that I forgot to change. The major mistake here was me not knowing that the `return true` value belonged outside of the loop.
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: `x==0` should be `x=0` or just eliminated since its redundant.

Comment: Your `return true;` is in the wrong place in `bool ptest(int y)`

Comment: [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would have helped.

Comment: Chapter4 **Exercise** 11... Whooo! For a moment I was worried Bjarne had gone bankrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors:

- Your `return true;` is in wrong position. It should be *after* the loop.
- `x` have to be updated in the iterations.

Warnings:

- The first expression `x==0` in `for` loop is meaningless.
- `p` is meaningless because its value is not used.

Try this:

```
bool ptest(int y)
{
    for (int x=0; x<primes.size(); ++x)
    {
        if (y%primes[x]==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Works, thank ya. The p was from a previous try that I must have forgotten to change to an x.